# Compare hourly data using python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Currently I am having two columns in dataframe one is timestamp and another is temperature which is received every 5 minutes. So data looks like:

```
timestamp                   temp
2021-03-21 00:02:17         35
2021-03-21 00:07:17         32
2021-03-21 00:12:17         33
2021-03-21 00:17:17         34
...
2021-03-21 00:57:19         33
2021-03-21 01:02:19         30
2021-03-21 01:07:19         31
...
```

Now if I want to compare each and every data on hourly basis how can I go ahead, I have tried df.resample() method but it just gives one result after every hour.

The result which I am expecting is like:
data at 00:02:17 - 35 and 01:02:19 - 30, So ans will be 35 -30 = 5
For second one 01:07:19 - 32 and 00:07:17 - 31, So ans will be 32 - 31 = 1

How can I do it dynamically such that it compares hourly data difference

Any help would be great.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please show the exact expected output (including the index column) for __more than two__ consecutive hours.

Comment: Check `shift `and `eq`  in pandas documentation

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
result_df = df.assign(minute_diff=df.sort_values('timestamp', ascending=False)
                                    .groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).dt.minute)['temp']
                                    .diff())
print(result_df)
            timestamp  temp  minute_diff
0 2021-03-21 00:02:17    35          5.0
1 2021-03-21 00:07:17    32          1.0
2 2021-03-21 00:12:17    33          NaN
3 2021-03-21 00:17:17    34          NaN
4 2021-03-21 00:57:19    33          NaN
5 2021-03-21 01:02:19    30          NaN
6 2021-03-21 01:07:19    31          NaN
```